# Is there any ax.view_init(elev, azim) equivalent function in plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using `Plots` for visualizing 3d-plots with Julia, and I am trying to change camera angle of my plot. In `matplotlib` in Python, I know that I can use `ax.view_init(elev, azim)` to change the camera angle, but on `Plot.jl`, I could not find solution to change the angle.

Is there any equivalent function with `ax.view_init(elev, azim)` in Python in Julia ?

**Example of Plot**

```
using Plots

plot()
for i in 1 : 5
    a = rand(10); b= rand(10); c = rand(10);
    plot!(a,b,c, seriestype=:scatter)
end
plot!()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in [the manual](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_subplot/) you can use the `camera` keyword argument (aliases are: `cam`, `cameras`, `view_angle`, `viewangle`). This argument sets the view angle for 3D plots. Its value is required to be a tuple `(azimuthal, elevation)` and the default setting is `(30, 30)`.